# How do i name a tab/column in CPP?

Tags: c++

I'm a new coder. Not really a coder yet just a freshman(1st semester) varsity student. So please forgive me if this is a stupid question....
how do i name a tab or column in cpp? I'm to make a program that collects names of students in my class along with their emails, phones and cgpas... i have to print the code in a tab which i did but i was wondering how do i name the tabs as in like under "Name" it would be names of all the students, under "Email" would be the emails of all the students etc. in like a vertical list view...

here's the code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
  string name;
  string email;
  string phone;
  double cgpa;
};

int main(void)
{
  

  Student students[3];
  double sum=0.0;
  double avg=0.0;

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    cout<<"\nPlease enter name"<<endl;
    cin>>students[i].name;
    cout<<"\nPlease enter email"<<endl;
    cin>>students[i].email;
    cout<<"\nPlease enter phone"<<endl;
    cin>>students[i].phone;
    cout<<"\nPlease enter cgpa"<<endl;
    cin>>students[i].cgpa;
  }
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Printing student info\n--------------"<<endl;
   
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout<<students[i].name<<"\t"<<students[i].email<<"\t"<<students[i].phone<<"\t"<<students[i].cgpa<<"\t"<<endl;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        sum+=students[i].cgpa;
    }
    avg=sum/3;
    cout<<"The average cgpa of the students = "<<avg;

getch();
}
```

Comment: You could simply print the names i.e. `email` etc to console and start outputting your info as you're already doing. You're already controlling the order of output for your student information

Comment: c++ doesnt know about columns. The columns are only there because you print the output with certain formatting. Print a line above the table and call that "header"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you print the student informations:

```
cout<<"Name\tEmail\tPhone\tcgpa\t"<<endl;
```

There are columns only because you are printing out some. There will be headers if you print out some.

Comment: also bro when i input a full name of a student error occurs... im guessing that's cause i have to use getline to write full name of students but how exactly would the syntax be?